# Why the operator is linear and continuous

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Let us $y_n$ a sequence of real numbers such that $\sum^{\infty} |x_ny_n| <\infty $ for all $x_n\in l^p$ and $f_j: l^p\to \mathbb R$ given by $f_j(x_n)=\sum_{i=1}^{j}x_i y_i$. Show that $f_j\in (l^p)'$.

My attempt was: $f_j$ is linear because $f_j(x_n +z_n)=\sum^{j}(x_n+z_n)y_n=\sum^{j}x_ny_n+\sum^{j}z_ny_n =f_j(x_n)+f_j(z_n)$.

To prove the continuity for me is no obvious because

$|f_j(x_n)|=|\sum^{j}x_ny_n|\leq \sum^{j}|x_ny_n|\leq \max_{1\leq n\leq j} \{y_n\}\sum^j |x_n|\leq \max_{1\leq n\leq j} \{y_n\}\sum^{\infty} |x_n| $

But how can put $|x_n|_{l^p}$? Other thing that i thought was to use Hölder inequality but i  do know if $y_n\in l^q$ so i am with problems

(I know that i need to prove that $|f(x)|\leq C|x|$. Other thing is, with the hypothesis i have $|f_j(x_n)|\leq \sum^{\infty}x_ny_n <\infty$, but is enough to know that an linear operator is bounded uniformly to say that is continuous? I am very confuse )

Thank you for the hints or answer please

Comment: Notice that $\pi_j(x) = x_j$ is continuous. Now, in $\mathbb{R}$, addition and multiplication are continuous.

Comment: Thank you @AndréCaldas i thought the same way, but when i saw the definition of functional defined in $X$ a banach or Hilbert space, i should prove that $|f(x)|\leq C||x||_{X}$ that was confuse for me

Comment: You are forgetting a constant: $|f(x)| \leq K \|x\|_X$. But in fact, for $\pi_j$, the constant can be $1$: $|\pi_j(x)| = |x_j| = \sqrt[p]{|x_j|^p} \leq \sqrt[p]{|x_1|^p + \dotsb + |x_j|^p + \dotsb} = \|x\|_p$.

Comment: @AndréCaldas thank you again. When you write $\pi_j(x)$ should be equal to $\sum _{i=i}^j x_iy_i$ right? with a projection above i get it, but with the sum is confuse for me, sorry i dont get it, intuitively i believe i understand

Comment: Your hypothesis that $\sum^{\infty} |x_ny_n| <\infty $ for all $x\in l^p$ is useless, since your $f_j$ only uses the coefficients $y_1,\dots,y_j.$ Your problem can be rephrased: prove that any linear combination of $\pi_1,\dots,\pi_j$ is linear and continuous, where each $\pi_k:\ell^p\to\mathbb R$ is the (linear and continuous) map $x\mapsto x_k.$

Comment: @AnneBauval thank you for you feetback..you right